# How to phrase that I have no interest in working outside my current location?

Tags: software-industry, linkedin, location

I'm a software engineer who's based in Galway (Ireland), and I've been getting a lot of headhunters trying to offer me jobs in other parts of the country or even outside Ireland. This is a bit of an occupational hazard*, but I have no interest in moving or working outside Galway, so I added a line about that to my LinkedIn profile summary a while ago to filter out as much noise as possible.

I just had another come in via LinkedIn for a job in Dublin. The note is at the bottom of the summary, so I'm reasonably sure they didn't see it. I don't know whether this is because LinkedIn's UI collapses the summary by default, or because they expanded the summary and then just skimmed it, or saw the note and decided that they know better anyway.

Would moving this note to the top of the summary be more effective?

---

**In another universe where they literally hunt heads using razor-sharp job specs, perhaps. Fortunately, I don't think I live in that one.*

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it probably isn't, but it would be nice to reduce the noise, even a little bit.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't move it to the top? If someone in your area is looking for candidates, they'll love it and as for everyone else, who cares.

Comment: I've had a similar note for years. Many recruiters will see that information and send it anyway. So, changing linkedin will not completely fix this. Might reduce the noise, though.

Comment: For some people, what they do is so important to them that they will move anywhere to be able to do it. For others, where they live is so important that they will take almost any job to be able to live there. I suspect most of us cluster towards the ends of the spectrum, not the middle. I'm near the "where I live" end, and tell people that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a resume include information that you are looking to relocate?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38876/should-a-resume-include-information-that-you-are-looking-to-relocate)

Comment: @HerbWolfe I don't think so...that's aimed more at a CV/resume, rather than a LinkedIn profile. The answers on that question are pretty useful - it would be unnecessary fluff on the CV - but I tend to use LinkedIn as the "full" resume (i.e. stuff that doesn't fit on 2 pages).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I've been getting a lot of headhunters trying to offer me jobs in other parts of the country or even outside Ireland.

This may be partly because you've changed your profile recently. A lot of recruiters seem to search for newly updated profiles, and even a small change can cause your profile to be included in their list. It may be partly due to your occupation, your connections, people adding endorsements, time of year, economic growth, etc. They're probably not actually offer jobs, of course, just looking for résumés to submit for interviews.

> Would moving this note to the top of the summary be more effective?

It might be *more* effective, or not, but it won't solve the problem. Some fraction of recruiters clearly don't bother to read your profile, and those that do read it are often looking for specific information. From their point of view, there's no harm in asking if you're interested.

If you're not really looking for a different job, changing your privacy settings so that people outside your network can't see as much information about you might be effective.

Comment: I have updated my profile a bit, but I set it to not display profile updates. It wouldn't surprise me if that affects _only_ my network, i.e. people I'm already connected with.

Comment: I think having a look back at the privacy settings again would be the most useful thing to do.

Answer (score 13):

Have a following text at hand:

> Thank you for reaching out. I would gladly receive an offer concerning an assignment in Galway as I'm not interested in commuting above X minutes a day and relocation is currently not an option for me.

Copy-paste it in the answer to the recruiter. Or ignore the offer.

Let's face it - you've became (semi)automatically targeted by the recruiter, respond in the same manner.

Answer (score 5):

You won't really change anything, even putting it at the top of your profile in 72 pt text.  There are two things the recruiter is hoping:

1. This job they have presented is amazingly, exactly, what you've always wanted and you will ignore everything you've said and go for it anyway.
2. If not, you'll know someone else similar who might be interested.

So most recruiters will completely ignore your statement, especially the poorer quality ones.  The main thing is to decide if you want to keep the recruiter connection for another time.

If yes, then reply and kindly put the recuiter right, if they are good they will respond to your requests.

If they don't (or don't look like the kind of recuiter you want to deal with), just stop responding, these people have hide like a rhino, and will happily come back and annoy you the next time you fit their brief (I've been very rude to many crappy recruiters, and like clockwork they came back next time it looked like I could earn them money).